# Database log unavailable

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2005 and I see the following message in event log (event id 9001)

"The log for database xxxx is not available."

After doing some research I found that it could be a corrupted database or possibly I/O related problem.
I tried running DBCC CHECKDB and it did not report any problem. At the end it shows following message:

"***CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors***"

I just want to know if there could be any damage to the database or log and what other steps I have to perform to verify it?

Comment: serverfault.com

Comment: Can anybody help. Does 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors need any attention?

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

1. Is your Log file size set to a limit?
2. Have you run out of disk space on the drive where the log file resides (seems unlikely)?
3. Is this a physical or virtual server?
4. What service pack are you running?
5. What, if any, are the preceding errors in the error log?

Comment: 1. No
2. No, There is enough disk space
3. Physical server
4. Sql Server 2005 (SP2). For time being I am using express edition.
5. There was no preceding error.


My database size is not quite big. it is just approx 100MB. I am just wondering that memory pressure on server is not a culprit. DB instance is already using the max limit (1 GB).

Answer (score -1):

Try to detach and reattach the database. If you encounter any problems, check out SQL Server log files. They might contain useful info. Note that each of the instances has it's own error logs. The easiest way to access SQL Server logs is in SSMS:

1. In Object Explorer, expand a SQL Server instance
2. Expand Management
3. Expand SQL Server Logs
4. Right-click a log and click View SQL Server Log

Comment: Nooooooooo.... don't do this. http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/A-SQL-Server-DBA-myth-a-day-%282130%29-corruption-can-be-fixed-by-restarting-SQL-Server.aspx